# AWS S3 rights issue when downloading buket folder.

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a folder in an Amazon S3 Bucket. I´m uploading .csv files to that folder with AJAX from an external webpage. When I tried to synchronize that folder with a local folder on my computer, I get an access denied error. This issue happen only with this folder that is receiving its content from "outside" of the AWS S3 web interface . If I manually upload a file to that folder from the AWS S3 interface then later I can synchronize it.

Also from within the AWS S3 web interface, if I try to download (by selecting the file and click on the Download button) any of the files that is being uploaded through the AJAX request, then I get also an access denied error.

I have tried with my root user, and also created an Administrator user on AIM, with full access and is also not working.

Hope someone can help me,

Best.

Comment: Is the permission correctly set of IAM user which you use to synchronize the bucket from AWS CLI?

Comment: It sounds like the core of your problem is that you may be allowing anonymous write access to your bucket.  How exactly are these AJAX uploads being authenticated?

Comment: The AJAX call are not authenticated... I just created a folder on the bucket and set it public so I can post files to it.

Comment: Right... don't do that.  You don't own files that are anonymously uploaded, so the inability to access them is expected.